# Build a pyramid with Frames

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I would like to build a pyramid with `Frame` elements in Xamarin.Forms. I would like to use a `Grid` layout, but it is difficult since the frames on the next row will overlap. What is the best layout to use in this situation? `StackLayout`, `AbsoluteLayout` or something else?

[image: Pyramid like this]

Comment: build each row as a separate Grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this using `AbsoluteLayout` and would generate the pyramid in the code-behind. It will save you a lot of typing and will be even faster.

The rough code for this would be:

```cs
private void BuildPyramid()
{
    int cellSize = 40;
    int height = 8;

    for (int row = 0; row < height - 1; row++) //one less to have two cells on top row
    {
        //add "empty" space equal to a multiple of half-size of a cell
        int startX = row * cellSize / 2; 
        var numberOfColumns = height - row; //each row has one less cell
        for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++)
        {
            var x = column * cellSize + startX;
            var y = (height - row - 1) * cellSize; //y-axis decreases going down
            var frame = new Frame()
            {
                WidthRequest = cellSize,
                HeightRequest = cellSize,
                Margin = new Thickness(2), 
                BorderColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
            };
            AbsLayout.Children.Add(frame);
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(frame, new Rectangle(x, y, cellSize, cellSize));
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: Result]

As a side note, if you are looking for a XAML-only approach - the `Grid` approach is also possible, but you have to do a trick here - you must add twice as many columns as you have cells in the widest row, to use half-width of a cell for layout and also utilize `Grid.ColumnSpan` to make the `Frames` always span 2 columns at once:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Frame">
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="CornflowerBlue" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15"  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- top row -->
    <Frame Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Frame Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

    <!-- bottom row -->
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
</Grid>
```

Yields:

[image: Sample Grid]

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems like exactly what I needed. I can`t wait to try it out.

Comment: Let me know how it went :-)

Comment: I go for the Absolutlayout approach. I have now tested it, and it works like a charm. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Happy coding and happy holidays !